# Asynchronously Log4j2 JDBC Appender "Unable to write to database"

Tags: java, spring, log4j2, oracle19c

Created log4j2.xml file under src/main/resources folder as below:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="INFO" monitorInterval="30">
    <Properties>
        <Property name="log-path">logs</Property>
        <Property name="enable-jndi">true</Property>
    </Properties>
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout
                pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n" />
        </Console>
        <JDBC name="databaseAppender" tableName="LOG_TABLE">

            <ConnectionFactory
                class="com.example.demo.ConnectionFactory"
                method="getDatabaseConnection" />
            <Column name="LOG_LEVEL" isUnicode="false" pattern="%level" />
            <Column name="CLASS_NAME" isUnicode="false" pattern="%C" />
            <Column name="METHOD_NAME" isUnicode="false" pattern="%M" />
            <Column name="LINE_NUMBER" isUnicode="false" pattern="%L" />
            <Column name="MESSAGE" isUnicode="false" pattern="%m" />
            <Column name="THREAD_NAME" isUnicode="false" pattern="%t" />
            <Column name="TIMESTAMP" isUnicode="false"
                pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}" />
        </JDBC>
        <Async name="AsyncOracle" bufferSize="262144"
            includeLocation="true">
            <AppenderRef ref="databaseAppender" />
        </Async>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console" />
            <AppenderRef ref="AsyncOracle" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Also created the DB connection file as:

```
    import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.sql.SQLException;
    
    import javax.sql.DataSource;
    
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
    
    import oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource;
    
    public class ConnectionFactory {
        
        @Value("${spring.datasource.url}")
        private String url;
    
        @Value("${spring.datasource.username}")
        private String username;
    
        @Value("${spring.datasource.password}")
        private String password;
    
        @Value("${spring.datasource.driver-class-name}")
        private String driver;
        
        private static interface Singleton {
            final ConnectionFactory INSTANCE = new ConnectionFactory();
        }
    
        @Bean
        public DataSource dataSource() throws SQLException {
            OracleDataSource dataSource = new OracleDataSource();
            dataSource.setURL(url);
            dataSource.setUser(username);
            dataSource.setPassword(password);
            dataSource.setURL(url);
            dataSource.setImplicitCachingEnabled(true);
            dataSource.setFastConnectionFailoverEnabled(true);
            dataSource.setDriverType("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            return dataSource();
        }
    
    
        public static Connection getDatabaseConnection() throws SQLException {
            return Singleton.INSTANCE.dataSource().getConnection();
        }
    }
```

application.properties file as:

```
    spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe
    spring.datasource.username=test
    spring.datasource.password=test
    spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
    
    logging.config=classpath:log4j2.xml
    Log4j2.enableJndiJdbc=true
```

But still facing the below error:

```
    2023-05-03 16:38:05,150 Log4j2-AsyncAppenderEventDispatcher-2-AsyncOracle ERROR Unable to write to database [JdbcManager{name=databaseAppender, bufferSize=0, tableName=LOG_TABLE, columnConfigs=[{ name=LOG_LEVEL, layout=%level, literal=null, timestamp=false }, { name=CLASS_NAME, layout=%C, literal=null, timestamp=false }, { name=METHOD_NAME, layout=%M, literal=null, timestamp=false }, { name=LINE_NUMBER, layout=%L, literal=null, timestamp=false }, { name=MESSAGE, layout=%m, literal=null, timestamp=false }, { name=THREAD_NAME, layout=%t, literal=null, timestamp=false }, { name=TIMESTAMP, layout=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}, literal=null, timestamp=false }], columnMappings=[]}] for appender [databaseAppender]. org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AppenderLoggingException: Error writing to JDBC Manager 'JdbcManager{name=databaseAppender, bufferSize=0, tableName=LOG_TABLE, columnConfigs=[{ name=LOG_LEVEL, layout=%level, literal=null, timestamp=false }, { name=CLASS_NAME, layout=%C, literal=null, timestamp=false }, { name=METHOD_NAME, layout=%M, literal=null, timestamp=false }, { name=LINE_NUMBER, layout=%L, literal=null, timestamp=false }, { name=MESSAGE, layout=%m, literal=null, timestamp=false }, { name=THREAD_NAME, layout=%t, literal=null, timestamp=false }, { name=TIMESTAMP, layout=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}, literal=null, timestamp=false }], columnMappings=[]}': JDBC connection not available [columnConfigs=[{ name=LOG_LEVEL, layout=%level, literal=null, timestamp=false }, { name=CLASS_NAME, layout=%C, literal=null, timestamp=false }, { name=METHOD_NAME, layout=%M, literal=null, timestamp=false }, { name=LINE_NUMBER, layout=%L, literal=null, timestamp=false }, { name=MESSAGE, layout=%m, literal=null, timestamp=false }, { name=THREAD_NAME, layout=%t, literal=null, timestamp=false }, { name=TIMESTAMP, layout=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}, literal=null, timestamp=false }], sqlStatement=insert into LOG_TABLE (LOG_LEVEL,CLASS_NAME,METHOD_NAME,LINE_NUMBER,MESSAGE,THREAD_NAME,TIMESTAMP) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?), factoryData=FactoryData [connectionSource=factory{ public static java.sql.Connection com.example.demo.ConnectionFactory.getDatabaseConnection() }, tableName=LOG_TABLE, columnConfigs=[{ name=LOG_LEVEL, layout=%level, literal=null, timestamp=false }, { name=CLASS_NAME, layout=%C, literal=null, timestamp=false }, { name=METHOD_NAME, layout=%M, literal=null, timestamp=false }, { name=LINE_NUMBER, layout=%L, literal=null, timestamp=false }, { name=MESSAGE, layout=%m, literal=null, timestamp=false }, { name=THREAD_NAME, layout=%t, literal=null, timestamp=false }, { name=TIMESTAMP, layout=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}, literal=null, timestamp=false }], columnMappings=[], immediateFail=false, retry=true, reconnectIntervalMillis=5000, truncateStrings=true], connection=null, statement=null, reconnector=Reconnector [latch=java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch@3829a5de[Count = 0], shutdown=false], isBatchSupported=false, columnMetaData=null]
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.db.jdbc.JdbcDatabaseManager.checkConnection(JdbcDatabaseManager.java:507)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.db.jdbc.JdbcDatabaseManager.connectAndStart(JdbcDatabaseManager.java:610)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.db.jdbc.JdbcDatabaseManager.writeThrough(JdbcDatabaseManager.java:888)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.db.AbstractDatabaseManager.write(AbstractDatabaseManager.java:264)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.db.AbstractDatabaseAppender.append(AbstractDatabaseAppender.java:110)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.tryCallAppender(AppenderControl.java:156)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.callAppender0(AppenderControl.java:129)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.callAppenderPreventRecursion(AppenderControl.java:120)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.callAppender(AppenderControl.java:84)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AsyncAppenderEventDispatcher.dispatch(AsyncAppenderEventDispatcher.java:118)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AsyncAppenderEventDispatcher.dispatchAll(AsyncAppenderEventDispatcher.java:80)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AsyncAppenderEventDispatcher.run(AsyncAppenderEventDispatcher.java:62)
```

Dependencies used:

```
    <parent>
           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
           <version>2.7.11</version>
           <relativePath />
           <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
       </parent>
       <dependencies>
           <dependency>
               <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
               <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
           </dependency>
           <dependency>
               <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
               <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
               <exclusions>
                   <exclusion>
                       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                       <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                   </exclusion>
               </exclusions>
           </dependency>
           <dependency>
               <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
               <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
               <scope>test</scope>
           </dependency>
           <dependency>
               <groupId>com.lmax</groupId>
               <artifactId>disruptor</artifactId>
               <version>3.4.2</version>
           </dependency>
           <dependency>
               <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
               <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
               <version>19.8.0.0</version>
           </dependency>
           <dependency>
               <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
               <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
               <version>2.14.1</version>
           </dependency>
       </dependencies>
```

We are trying to persist the logging messages in database asynchronously using Log4j2, but facing issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring will inject the `@Value` annotated fields only in beans **managed** by Spring (it means created and destroyed by Spring). Your `ConnectionFactory` is not managed: you instantiate it in the static initializer of your class. Therefore all its fields have `null` as value and the connection fails.

#### How to use the JDBC appender in Spring Boot

Logging in a Spring Boot application is configured at least twice:

- before the [`ApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/context/event/ApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent.html) Spring's environment (e.g. `application.properties`) is not available and the native Log4j 2.x Core configuration process is used (cf. [documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#AutomaticConfiguration)). Therefore you **can not** use the JDBC appender in your `log4j2.xml` file.
- after the event is fired a reconfiguration is triggered, which uses `log4j2-spring.xml` if available. In this configuration file you **can** use Spring's environment thanks to the [Spring Lookup](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-spring-boot.html#spring-lookup).

What you are attempting to do can be done in a `log4j2-spring.xml` configuration file with an appender definition like this:

```xml
<JDBC name="databaseAppender" tableName="LOG_TABLE">
  <DriverManager connectionString="${spring:spring.datasource.url}"
                 driverClassName="${spring:spring.datasource.driver-class-name}"
                 userName="${spring:spring.datasource.username}"
                 password="${spring:spring.datasource.password}"/>
  <Column name="LOG_LEVEL" isUnicode="false" pattern="%level"/>
  <Column name="CLASS_NAME" isUnicode="false" pattern="%C"/>
  <Column name="METHOD_NAME" isUnicode="false" pattern="%M"/>
  <Column name="LINE_NUMBER" isUnicode="false" pattern="%L"/>
  <Column name="MESSAGE" isUnicode="false" pattern="%m"/>
  <Column name="THREAD_NAME" isUnicode="false" pattern="%t"/>
  <Column name="TIMESTAMP" isUnicode="false" pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}"/>
</JDBC>
```

#### Dependencies configuration

You need to upgrade `log4j-core`, since the version you are using has multiple security vulnerabilities.

Spring Boot is very opinionated about artifact versions: since you are using `spring-boot-starter-parent` you have more than a hundred [managed dependencies](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#dependency-management). IMHO the general rule about Spring Boot dependencies is:

- don't override a version (don't provide a `<version>` property) if Spring Boot manages it. In your POM only `disruptor` is **not** managed by Spring Boot,
- don't use a direct dependency if there is a starter for it. For Log4j 2.x Core Spring Boot provides [`spring-boot-starter-log4j2`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-log4j2).

Therefore your Maven dependencies should look like:

```xml
<dependencies>
  <!-- Replace if you are using a different logging API -->
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <!--
    ~ These are not used directly in your code, hence the `runtime` scope.
    -->
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
  </dependency>
  <!-- Not managed by Spring Boot -->
  <!-- Version suggested by `log4j-core` 2.20.0 -->
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.lmax</groupId>
    <artifactId>disruptor</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.4</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
  </dependency>
  <!-- Contains Spring Lookup -->
  <!-- Not required any more in Spring Boot 3.x -->
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-spring-boot</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

**Edit:**

**Remark:** you don't need LMAX `disruptor` to use asynchronous **appenders**. You would need it for asynchronous **loggers**. Asynchronous loggers give you a considerable performance bust (cf. [benchmark](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/async.html#asynchronous-logging-performance)), but asynchronous loggers + asynchronous appender will probably slow down to the performance of an asynchronous appender.