# Log the custom message to RMQ asynchronously using Log4j2

Tags: java, spring-boot, rabbitmq, log4j2

1. log4j2-spring.xml config file created under src/main/resources:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="INFO">
    <Appenders>
        <RabbitMQ name="rmqAppender" host="${rabbitmq.in.host}"
            port="${rabbitmq.in.port}"
            virtualHost="${rabbitmq.in.virtualhost}"
            username="${rabbitmq.in.username}"
            password="${rabbitmq.in.password}"
            exchange="${rabbitmq.in.exchange}"
            routingKey="${rabbitmq.in.routingkey}">
            <PatternLayout
                pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n" />
        </RabbitMQ>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="com.example.demo" level="info" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="rmqAppender" />
        </Logger>
        <Root level="info">
            <!-- <AppenderRef ref="Console" /> -->
            <AppenderRef ref="rmqAppender" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

2. Application.properties file is:

```
rabbitmq.in.queue=queue
rabbitmq.in.exchange=exchange
rabbitmq.in.routingkey=routingkey
rabbitmq.in.host=host
rabbitmq.in.port=port
rabbitmq.in.exchangetype=exchangetype
rabbitmq.in.virtualhost=virtualhost
rabbitmq.in.username=username
rabbitmq.in.password=password
listener.prefetchcount=1
listener.maxConcurrentConsumerCount=10
management.health.rabbit.enabled=false

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe
spring.datasource.username=test
spring.datasource.password=test
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
    
logging.config=classpath:log4j2.xml
```

3. pom.xml is used is (spring-boot version-2.7.11)

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.14.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
        <version>19.8.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.rabbitmq</groupId>
        <artifactId>amqp-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

But facing the error related to configuration file as shown below:

```
Logging system failed to initialize using configuration from 'classpath:log4j2-spring.xml'
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Logback configuration error detected: 
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@7:13 - no applicable action for [Appenders], current ElementPath  is [[Configuration][Appenders]]
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@38:47 - no applicable action for [RabbitMQ], current ElementPath  is [[Configuration][Appenders][RabbitMQ]]
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@40:69 - no applicable action for [PatternLayout], current ElementPath  is [[Configuration][Appenders][RabbitMQ][PatternLayout]]
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@43:11 - no applicable action for [Loggers], current ElementPath  is [[Configuration][Loggers]]
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@44:66 - no applicable action for [Logger], current ElementPath  is [[Configuration][Loggers][Logger]]
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@45:35 - no applicable action for [AppenderRef], current ElementPath  is [[Configuration][Loggers][Logger][AppenderRef]]
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@47:22 - no applicable action for [Root], current ElementPath  is [[Configuration][Loggers][Root]]
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@49:37 - no applicable action for [AppenderRef], current ElementPath  is [[Configuration][Loggers][Root][AppenderRef]]
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.loadConfiguration(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:179)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.AbstractLoggingSystem.initializeWithSpecificConfig(AbstractLoggingSystem.java:66)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.AbstractLoggingSystem.initialize(AbstractLoggingSystem.java:57)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.initialize(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:132)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.initializeSystem(LoggingApplicationListener.java:332)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.initialize(LoggingApplicationListener.java:298)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:246)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:223)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:176)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:169)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:143)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:131)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:85)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.lambda$environmentPrepared$2(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:66)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:120)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:114)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:65)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:343)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:301)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1303)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1292)
    at com.example.demo.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:12)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Logback configuration error detected:
```

Need to send the logging custom json message to RMqueue, using asynchronous log4j2 configuration.

Comment: Most of the remarks to [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76163488/11748454) apply also here: use the `${spring:...}` lookup and fix up your dependencies (you are again using a version vulnerable to [Log4Shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log4Shell)). Unlike your previous application, this one lacks the exclusion of `spring-boot-starter-logging` from `spring-boot-starter`.

Comment: I have applied those changes, but still facing issues,


`2023-05-08 10:13:20,605 main ERROR Error processing element RabbitMQ ([Appenders: null]): CLASS_NOT_FOUND
2023-05-08 10:13:20,625 main ERROR Unable to locate appender "rmqAppender" for logger config "root"`

Comment: The `RabbitMQ` appender is provided by Spring in [`org.springframework.amqp:spring-rabbit`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.amqp/spring-rabbit). Add it as runtime dependency.

Comment: Still the same issue persist

Comment: If you still have `CLASS_NOT_FOUND` after adding `spring-rabbit`, check your deployment configuration. The usual suspect is deploying a fat-jar with a misconfigured Maven Shade plugin (cf. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76015329/11748454)).